# from strings with double quotes to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
"one"
"two"
"three"
```

Above is an output from ajax. How can I convert them into an array?

```
["one","two","three"]
```

I tried push() and split but the output is always ["one"]["two"]["three"]

```js
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1VC633BXpMElJjRWvIRuZIP7UrEhuw6BdscnrV2heox0/1/public/full?alt=json',
        success: function(data) {
            var entry = data.feed.entry;
        //console.log(entry);
    for (var x in entry) {
      numbers = entry[x].gsx$numbers.$t;
      aaa = numbers.split();
      console.log(aaa); 
    }

        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Please show the string. And using `split` will be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation :** `[...  ]` converts the `entry` into an array. Using `map` function, returns all those `strings`. However, they may include `empty strings`. That is why I have used `filter`, which filters out the `strings` with non-zero length, and assigns the resultant array to `arr` :)

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1VC633BXpMElJjRWvIRuZIP7UrEhuw6BdscnrV2heox0/1/public/full?alt=json',
    success: function(data) {
      var entry = data.feed.entry;
      
      var arr = [...entry].map((el)=>{
        return el.gsx$numbers.$t;
      }).filter((el) => {
        return el.trim();
      });
      console.log(arr);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```